# hosting nodeJS/mongoose web application on amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mongoose

i would like to host a nodeJS/mongoose/mongodb application in a cloud, and since EC2 has a MicroInstance that's free for 1 year, my question is: **Are there any step-by-step tutorials how can I get up and running nodejs/mongoose application in Amazon EC2?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used a couple of guides that really helped me out on putting a Node.js application on Amazon EC2.

The first one guides you through the creation of the instance and the installation of Node.js on that instance

[How to setup Node.js on Amazon EC2 - Complete Guide](http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/)

And then there's another one which could also be helpful to you, it has some more details about how making the Node.js app available on port 80 by tweaking iptables to forward it to port 8080

[How I got Node.js running on Amazon EC2](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2321-How-I-Got-Node-js-Running-On-A-Linux-Micro-Instance-Using-Amazon-EC2.htm)

For MongoDB, there's an official guide to se it up on Amazon EC2 on the official website

[MongoDB on Amazon EC2](http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Amazon%20EC2.html)

If you're just prototyping an application you may also consider using the free tier (500 MB) on [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com) for creating your MongoDB instance without any effort, that will also save some resources on your EC2 micro instance running the Node.js application.

Comment: Can I create my MongoDB db on AWS free tier on my existing EC2 instance where nodejs app is running? Is mongoDB free to use on AWS for free tier users?
If not then how can i setup mongoDB for free on my AWS EC2 free app ?

Comment: If you use a single EC2 instance running both the app and mongo, of course you can. As long as you don't use more EC2 machines. Another option would be using free mongodb hosting services like https://www.compose.io or https://mongolab.com

Comment: Okay thanks means I just need to install mongo db on my EC2 linux machine and connect my nodejs app with it?, but how do i make sure I don't exceed my free tier limits, how do I check how much of memory/storage my mongoDB is using on my EC2 in total ? According to AWS, for EC2 they don't mention the storage limit they just say 750 hours per month. https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: It says 750 hours per month for a t2.micro instance, so you can only use a t2.micro instance active at all times, and it will be free for a year.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Amazon's AMI

creating an upstart script for your js app

the following file can go in /etc/init

## nodeapp.conf

```
description "node app"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on runlevel [016]

console owner

exec /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/app; /usr/bin/node server.js -p 9001'

respawn
```

from here you want to use nginx or apache to proxy to your node app

nginx can be installed via `yum install nginx`

for nginx the following block would work in your http {} config block

```
upstream app_cluster_1 {
server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_pass http://app_cluster_1/;
proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

you can then start your app and nginx

`start nodeapp`

and

`service nginx start/restart`

if you are hosting mongo-db locally make sure to start it as well. I believe it ships with an init.d script

`service mongod start`

to auto run nginx and mongo

`chkconfig nginx on`

`chkconfig mongod on`

if mongo is not available as a package follow the steps on

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I have written down step by step, how to setup node.js app in EC2 instance which I follow, it just takes a half hour to setup server in EC2 for me by following these steps

```
Step1: Create EC2 Instance with ubuntu, eligible for a free tier

Step2: click on connect button after successfully creating the instance.

step3: then follow the steps- In your terminal
       chmod 400 yourpemfile.pem
       after this copy, the line shown in the example and paste it into your terminal.
```

Now you are logged in successfully to your EC2 Instance.

```
Step4: install all dependencies listed below.
       Nodejs
       npm
       mongodb
       git - this will be already installed in your instance, try typing git.
       pm2
```

Now we have installed all the dependencies which we required for node.js app to run

```
step5: clone your project
       Go to your latest branch

       Install dependencies (npm install) or simply type yarn
```

Now if you are keeping a copy of .env file as env.example or something relevant to that, then type this to copy your file cp .env.example .env
to copy and create .env file

```
here I am copying .env.example file and creating a new file named .env

Step6: Now go on running instance scroll down and find security group.
       Here you will find launch wizard, click on it.
       Now click on inbound rules, and then click on edit button.
       Now click on add rule.
       select custom tcp.
       enter the port number which your node.js app is using.
       Select range anywhere, so that you can access from anywhere you want to.
```

Now come to your terminal you have connected to EC2 instance.

```
Step7: Build your project

Step8: create server.sh file out from your project which you cloned.
       Here type cd path-from-where-you-would-do-yarn-start/node index.js
```

For creating server.sh file type nano server.sh
This will open text editor.
start typing as shown in step 8
To exit this press ctrl+o then press enter and then ctrl+x
    Now you have successfully created server.sh file

```
step9: Now where your server.sh file is located, here type
       pm2 start server.sh --name=name-you-like
```

Now your Node.js Server is up and running, have a great day.

> Tips

```
Tips: 
Form next time.

  To see your list of a servers running type pm2 list.

  To stop your server type pm2 stop name-of-server-you-want-to-stop.

  To start pm2 start name-of-server-you-want-to-start.

  To restart pm2 restart name-of-server-you-want-to-restart
```

If this helped, please vote for it.Thanks

Comment: If anyone needs the link or commands to install dependencies in ubuntu machine for node.js. Then just let me know.